# Binary tree implementation for language analyse - child as node: does not work

Tags: c++, parsing, tree, abstract-syntax-tree

I have been trying for some time to implement an AST in C++ to store data that has been derived from an ML language, here is an instruction that my AST manages to record:

```
var foo = 8;
```

The lexer isolates the tokens, and the parser infers that it is a variable declaration, so it isolates the whole:

```
foo = 8
```

From this it was easy to build a temporary AST:

```
    =  
  /   \
foo    8
```

But I still can't handle the child-nodes:

```
foo = 2 + 4
```

Or

```
foo : integer = 2 + 4
```

So who should give this:

```
         =      
       /   \    
      /     \   
     :       +  
    / \     / \ 
   /   \   2   4
 foo integer
```

Here is my implementation attempt:

*.hpp

```
enum NodeTypes { /* ... */ };

struct Node {
    token_t NodeValue;
    NodeTypes NodeType;
    Node *LeftChild = NULL;
    Node *RightChild = NULL;
    Node(token_t value, NodeTypes type);
    void InsertLeft(token_t NodeValue, NodeTypes NodeType = NOTHING);
    void InsertRight(token_t NodeValue, NodeTypes NodeType = NOTHING);
    void BrowseUp();
};
```

*.cpp

```
Node(token_t value, NodeTypes type) {
    NodeValue = value;
    NodeType = type;
}
void InsertLeft(token_t value, NodeTypes type) {
    if (LeftChild == NULL)
        LeftChild = new Node(value, type);
    else {
        Node NewNode = Node(value, type);
        NewNode.LeftChild = LeftChild;
        LeftChild = &NewNode;
    }
}
void InsertRight(token_t value, NodeTypes type) {
    if (RightChild == NULL)
        RightChild = new Node(value, type);
    else {
        Node NewNode = Node(value, type);
        NewNode.RightChild = RightChild;
        RightChild = &NewNode;
    }
}
void BrowseUp() {
    std::cout << NodeValue.value << " ";
    if (LeftChild) LeftChild->BrowseUp();
    if (RightChild) RightChild->BrowseUp();
}
```

Using it:

```
Node main = Node(NodePosition, NodeType);
SetMainAst(main, expr);
main.BrowseUp();
```

SetMainAst:

```
void SetMainAst(Node &node, Expr expr, NodeTypes type = NodeTypes::NOTHING) {
    std::array<Expr, 3> exp = CutExpr(expr, GetNodePosition(expr));
    Expr left = exp[0], right = exp[2];
    token_t value = exp[1][0];

    if (type == NOTHING) node.NodeValue = value;

    if (!ContainNodes(left)) node.InsertLeft(left[0]);
    else SetMainAst(node, left, DetermineFirstNode(expr));
    if (!ContainNodes(right)) node.InsertRight(right[0]);
    else SetMainAst(node, right, DetermineFirstNode(expr));
}
```

CutExpr() allows to cut an expression in 3:

- lvalue ;
- node ;
- rvalue.

I helped myself with [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/all-you-need-to-know-about-tree-data-structures-bceacb85490c) (it's in python, but I transcribed it in C++).

With a single node expression, it works wonders. But, when there is more than one node, it no longer works: BrowseUp() stops the program after displaying the main node (i.e. the equal sign in this case).

I really don't understand, but I well followed the tutorial well and think I transcribed well in C++... Maybe it's a pointer/reference problem?

I would be very grateful if you would help me solve this problem (which has been bothering me for 3 days).

Comment: `LeftChild = &NewNode;` -- pointer to local variable that outlives local scope

Comment: If you look at the error others have pointed out, take a look at the bigger picture to understand how what you are doing couldn't work.  How would you have implemented a destructor for your tree?  If you implemented it by calling `delete` on each node, you do realize that some of your nodes were not created with `new`, so you would have been stuck.

Comment: Supplemental viewing: (Warning: over an hour long) [Herb Sutter's Leak Freedom by Default presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE)

Comment: Note that your error really has nothing to do with AST and trees, but fundamental C++ knowledge.  You should first learn about proper memory management in C++ and variable scope (maybe implement a simple binary tree with proper construction *and* destruction).  It isn't like Python or similar languages, where garbage collection removes this aspect of programming from you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
    Node NewNode = Node(value, type);
    NewNode.LeftChild = LeftChild;
    LeftChild = &NewNode;
```

is wrong because you are storing a pointer to an object that is about to be destroyed (when you exit the `if ... else` statement).

You probably want something like this

```
    Node* NewNode = new Node(value, type);
    NewNode->LeftChild = LeftChild;
    LeftChild = NewNode;
```

You're transcribing from Python which has garbage collection to C++ which doesn't. Therefore you have to add memory management yourself.